# Doxygen sees java generic method as package protected

Tags: java, generics, doxygen

I have a java class that has methods like :

```java
private <T extends event> boolean _fire(Class<T> cls, T event);
public <T extends event> void fire(final T event);
```

I use Doxygen to generate the documentation for those methods. I know Javadoc is better for Java but it is a company policy and I'm required to use Doxygen.

The problem is doxygen reports those two methods as being `package protected`.

Doxygen shows :

```
package functions:
    private< T extends WeemoEvent > boolean    _fire (Class< T > cls, T event)
    public< T extends WeemoEvent > void        fire (final T event)
```

Which looks to me as if doxygen was seing the generic argument being associated to public or private.

Is there a way to correct this in doxygen ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Please file a bug report here https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen and attach a self-contained example (source+config file) in a tar or zip.

Comment: Done: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=710175

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding the first `<T>` with `/*! @cond x */` and `/*! @endcond */`, so it is ignored by Doxygen, helps, even though it's ugly (x can be any string, as long as it doesn't label an enabled condition).

see my answer to a related problem: [Doxygen losing non-static Java generic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359457/doxygen-losing-non-static-java-generic-methods/33165202#33165202)