# Doxygen losing non-static Java generic methods

Tags: java, doxygen

I'm running into an issue where Doxygen does not include non-static Java generic methods in the documentation. Methods using the following syntax are not found:

```
public <T> ReturnType<T> methodName(ArgType1 arg1, ArgType2<T> arg2) throws Exception{}
```

However, the following method declarations are both found and included in the documentation:

```
public static <T> ReturnType<T> methodName(ArgType1 arg1, ArgType2<T> arg2) throws Exception{}

public ReturnType<T> methodName(ArgType1 arg1, ArgType2<T> arg2) throws Exception{}
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: I'm curious: why are you using Doxygen instead of Javadocs for Java?

Comment: We are using Doxygen for a different platform and would like to use the same tool if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered it, too. Seems to me, that Java Generic Methods are not supported in Doxygen (at least in this particular version - I use 1.8.8-5) and thus ignored. `static` overrides this behavior, as it apparently makes Doxygen accept arbitrary strings as return type modifiers.

Surrounding the first `<T>` with `/*! @cond x */` and `/*! @endcond */`, so it is ignored by Doxygen, helps, even though it's ugly (x can be any string, as long as it doesn't label an enabled condition).